# jvectormap: how to change a regioncolor after map has been created

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I have tried to change the color of a specific region AFTER the map has been created.
Later on i want to do that with ajax calls, but for now i just want to add this action to a button.

```
$('#kleur').click(function(){
    //$('#map').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {US:'#8B0000'})
var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
map.setSelectedRegionStyle('US', '#b2c9cb');
  });
```

In html:

```
 <button id="kleur">Kleur</button>
```

Other code i have tried:

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
                var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
                var name = map.getRegionName(code);
                var message = 'You clicked  which has the code: '
                    + code.toUpperCase() + name; //  to json for ajax??

                //console.log('Name: ' + json['properties'][code]['name']);

                alert(message);
            }
    //backgroundColor:'#FFFF00',

    //setBackgroundColor('#FFFF00');

    //$('#map').vectorMap('set','color',{US:'#FFFF00'});

})
```

I like jvectormap, but the tutorials are bit too limited for me.
All found examples i have tried are in the posted code, to keep an overview i kept used codesnippets as comments in the code.

Many thanks in advance for any help!